# Angular Dashboard and PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) ERROR

Tags: linux, angularjs, node.js, npm, phantomjs

I am trying to build on local an environment to create my current BI tool. I would need [angular-dashboard-app](https://github.com/nickholub/angular-dashboard-app) or [malhar-angular-dashboard](https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard)

But, I am struggling when I run the command grunt to build, clean and deploy it.

It is appearing a lot of lines of errors with this pattern

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
    at /opt/nodejs/nwww/angular-dashboard-app/app/scripts/controllers/topics.js:3
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) ERROR

And at the end

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.148 secs / 0 secs)

I suppose it would be cause of missing a library like PhantomJS, but I've already installed and it is still appearing.
I have no idea what's is going on...Any suggestion & ideas?

node v0.10.33

Linux Mint 16 Petra 32bits.

Thx